# verifying when a property is set for a custom control

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I'm hoping there is a pattern for verifying when a property is set for a custom control in asp.net.

Considering that there is a page life cycle, we keep having issues where the control can get into an invalid state. The best thing we can do is raise an exception with an instructional message for things like, setting values selected before adding data.

Please note, ideally the component wouldn't rely on things like ordering of when a property is set. Unfortunately I can only move the company to better practices one step at a time. There are too many components to re-write from scratch and is an unrealistic expectation.

That said, here's an example.

We have two properties. SelectedValues which will set the values that match a comma separated list and InsertAll which will insert "All" at the top of a list.

Potential issue: The developer sets the SelectedValues in the Page's PreInit event, but the InsertAll property, if true, will add the "All" value and select it during the control's Init event. The trick is, SelectedValues will directly set the values when set, not later during the life cycle. Which means, when they see the page, they think there is a bug in the component because they didn't set All to be selected, but it is.

Page:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    listBoxSelection.SelectedValues = "value1,value2";
    listBoxSelection.InsertAll = true;
}
```

Control:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (this.InsertAll)
        {
            ListBoxItem allItem = new ListBoxItem()
                                  {
                                      Text = "All",
                                      Value = "0"
                                      Selected = true
                                  };

            this.Items.Insert(0, allItem);
        }
    }
```

How can I ensure that the developer knows they goofed when using this control? This is a simple example, but I see it all the time and in many forms.